# What set(s) are these 2x2 hexagon bricks from?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

I've inherited quite a few interesting pieces from relatives who outgrew LEGO. Any idea what set(s) these came in? They don't have any numbers so I can't look them up on pick-a-brick or anything.

[image]

Comment: Do these bricks have any "LEGO" markings on them? The most obvious place would be on the studs of the blue octogonal piece (2nd from the left). So far I haven't found anything yet that matches so I'm wondering if this is perhaps a clone brand ....

Comment: yes, they all have lego markings on them.

Comment: Now I need to get some and use them as pipes for a Mario bros. set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the following pieces:

1. [6037 - Brick, Modified Octagonal 2 x 2 x 3 1/3](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6037#T=C)

[image]

2. [6043 - Brick, Modified Octagonal 2 x 2 x 3 1/3 Corner](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6043#T=C)

[image]

3. [6042 - Brick, Modified Octagonal 2 x 2 x 3 1/3 with Side Studs](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6042#T=C)

[image]

4. [6032 - Brick, Modified Octagonal 2 x 3 x 1 2/3 Sloped](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6032&idColor=3#T=C&C=3)

[image]

These were used in about 10-15 sets during a brief period from 1995-1998, most of them in the Aquazone theme, but some made their way into other themes as well (e.g. Castle).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Those are modified octagonal bricks numbers 6037, 6042, 6043, and 6032.

http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=3&catString=7&catType=P

The blue corner pieces (6043) are only from set 6190-1 Shark's Crystal Cave

[image]

The others are likely from the 2162-1 Hydro Reef Wrecker

[image]